# Selenium Python: How can I count the number of tables in a div?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find an element with Xpath but it changes like so:

```
//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a
//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a
//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a
//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a
//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table[5]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a
//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table[6]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a
```

My current assumption is that the table I'm looking for will always be that last one in the table array but I want to confirm this by counting the number of tables in the second div. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is using the below xpath.

```
//*[@id='emailwrapper']/div/div/table
```

Your code should be

```
lastTable = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='emailwrapper']/div/div/table"))-1
print lastTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there would be at least one element that matches the xpath of '//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table', you can simply do:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table')
```

It will return a list, or raise NoSuchElementException if none are found.

Exact same results but written differently:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="emailwrapper"]/div/div/table')
```

After which you can do a len() on the list for how many elements